# Execute JS (Check FB Login) before html loads - Code included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

**How it works:**

The page ckecks out if the user is already logged in, if user is logged in the page redirects to another page using window.location.

**The problem:**

The first page loads the content of the page for just a moment before redirect to the other one. I want it to not show nothing until it checked login status

**What didn't work:**

I've tried placing the script on  and on  but it still loading the html.

**The solution I prefer not to use:**

Include the html through JS but it would make the code too confusing and harder to maintain after a long time..

**The Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <script>
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
            if(response.status == "connected"){
                window.location = "http://www.page.com/Logged.php";
            }
            });
    </script>


<p>Page content</p>  // THIS SHOULD WAIT UNTIL THE SCRIPT FINISH

</body>
</html>
```

**SOLUTION:**

The best approach is to include with jquery another file with the html code, right after the login script.

I add some code that can help:

firstFile.html:

```
    <html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("secondFile.html"); //INCLUDE THE SECOND FILE ON THE DIV BELOW
    });
    </script> 
  </head>
<body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>  //INCLUDE THE SECOND FILE HERE
</body> 
</html>
```

secondFile.html:

```
<p> This is my include file </p>
```

Comment: Well, you could try to embed the JS SDK synchronously (so it’ll block loading of other ressources), and use `FB.getAuthResponse`, which is also synchronous – and then redirect once its answer comes in. And you could setting `body` to `display:none`, so the user won’t see anything until that check is run. (Maybe combine it with a timeout that’ll make it visible anyway if the check should take too long.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just have the script print the page content after running? And you'd just have a separate file it gets the html out of or put all the html as a string in that script.

EDIT:
I would do this:

```
 <script>
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
        if(response.status == "connected"){
            window.location = "http://www.page.com/Logged.php";
        } else {
            window.location = "http://www.page.com/NotLogged.php";
        });
</script>
```

It sounds like you don't want to do that though. If you don't want to use the script I gave you, you could have the entire page in a div tag that is hidden/not visible by default and you could make the div visible after the script runs.

Comment: Better idea! Have the page with js have no html. And have that page redirect to your logged in page or your login page.

Comment: Nice aproach but then I wouldn´t be able to use my index.php file neithe my .com adress

Comment: If you could include some code as an example that would be the correct answer to me!

Comment: Can you explain why your index page cannot be a redirect page? And I'll get the code up when i get home!

Comment: It does, but then it will not display anything. Imagine facebook.com doesn´t show up nothing. It´s just not the best..